# Personal book library

Tags: python

Very new to OOP with Python - and feel like I still don't totally get OOP. However I thought I'd put together a personal online book library to practice inheritance, methods, docstrings etc.

Program allows one to add books (comics or novels - with comics inheriting from novels) to one's own library, and create a custom reading lists.

There are a few different methods. For example, a library method which will return all books over a specified length.

Note that I've removed quite a lot from this, just so it's not 5 pages long! I would normally have several different types of books, attributes such as Author etc. But hopefully from the below you get a good idea of the structure.

Speaking of structure, I would just like to know if mine is any good. Also there is an issue whereby if you remove a book from the library, it will still show up in any reading lists I created. I don't know if there's a way to deal with this, or if I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

```
class Library:
    
    def __init__(self, books = None):
        if books is None:
            self.books = []
        else:
            self.books = books

    def add_book(self, book):
        self.books.append(book)
        
    def remove_book(self, book):
        self.books.remove(book)
        
    def pages_over_n(self, number):
        """Returns books that have more than specified number of pages"""
        return [book for book in self.books if book.pages > number]
    
    def get_library(self):
        """Returns all books in Library"""
        return self.books
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Library({self.books})"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Library has {len(self.books)}"

class Novel:
    
    def __init__(self, title, pages, publicationDate):
        self.title = title
        self.pages = pages
        self.publicationDate = publicationDate
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Novel({self.title}, {self.pages}, {self.publicationDate})"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Media: {self.title}"
    
class ComicBook(Novel):
    
    def __init__(self, title, pages, publicationDate, artist):
        super().__init__(title, pages, publicationDate)
        self.artist = artist
        
    def get_artist(self):
        return f"Artist: {self.artist}"
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"ComicBook({self.title}, {self.pages}, " 
                f"{self.publicationDate}, {self.artist})")
    
class ReadingList:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
    
    def add_book(self, book):
        """Add book to reading list"""
        self.list.append(book)
        
    def remove_book(self, book):
        """Remove book from reading list"""
        self.list.remove(book)

    def total_pages(self):
        """Returns total pages in reading list"""
        total = 0
        for book in self.list:
            total += book.pages
        return total

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ReadingList({self.list})"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Reading list of size {len(self.list)}"

# Initialise Library
library = Library()

# Create a few books
novel1 = Novel("Harry Potter", 500, 1991)
novel2 = Novel("LotR", 1000, 1960)
novel3 = Novel("Game of Thrones", 2000, 2018)
comic1 = ComicBook("Batman", 100, 2020, "Stan Lee")

# Add books to library.
library.add_book(novel1)
library.add_book(novel2)
library.add_book(novel3)
library.add_book(comic1)

# Create a new reading list.
readingListOne = ReadingList()

# Add a couple of books to reading list.
readingListOne.add_book(novel1)
readingListOne.add_book(comic1)
```

Comment: Long code is not frowned upon in [codereview.se]. For a big-ish project, you can also put the code on git(hub/lab) etc and include the specific file/code you want reviewed in the post here, linking to the project for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had the feeling that people would only be interested in looking over short code. There isn't too much more to add at the moment (still working through it) - jus wanted to check I was on the right lines.

Comment: @AaronWright Do you have to do OOP? A lot of people (including myself) don't like it, and would prefer to do a functional style.

Comment: There is no persistence of data yet.

Comment: @dwjohnston You don't like OOP and your top tag is java?

Comment: @AryanParekh I don't have an especially active profile on Code Review. I mostly use JavaScript.

Comment: @AaronWright Consider accepting any answer :)

Comment: OOP and functional "style" are not mutually exclusive. A lot of the encapsulation, scope, composition goals look very OOPish to me. As for JavaScript, it is an "object based" language and its features allow a very OO design approach. Breaking down complexity into interacting objects is a powerful paradigm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## General Observations

I'm being 100% honest here, When I just give a glance at your code there is nothing that is immediately horrifying with it.

- You shouldn't use variable/function names that are already defined in Python. Your class `ReadingList` has an attribute `list`. This is a bad idea as there is already a `list` keyword that can clash with your definition

## Code Structure

You have tried to implement the idea of inheritance, although it is fine, it will be much better to have your base class as `Book`.
[image: b]

This makes more sense due to the fact that novels, and comic books **are types of books**. And hence can share attributes and methods.

Your `Book` class can have attributes and methods like

- Author
- Name
- Stuff which is common in all types of books

And your child class `Novel` can have

- Sutff which is special in Novel

A very very basic implementation

```py
class Book():
    def __init__(self,author,name):
        self.author = author
        self.name = name

    def print_book(self):
        print(f"{self.name} by {self.author}")




class Novel(Book):
    def __init__(self,author,name):
        Book.__init__(self,author,name)

    def display(self):
        print(f"The Novel {self.name}")
        # Novel stuff which isn't common in all books

class Comic(Book):
    def __init__(self,author,name):
        Book.__init__(self,author,name)

    def display(self):
        print(f"The comic book {self.name}")
        # Comic book stuff which isn't common in all books
        

nov = Novel("J.K Rowling","Harry Potter")
nov.print_book()
```

The point is that your `Novel` class is basically a `Book` which as an author, pages, etc. But it also has something which other books like `Comic` don't. This way you don't need to create an entirely new class, but you can simply inherit the common from the `Book` class and add the extra stuff in `Novel`

---

## Creating a library

You can stop here if you want to, and consider your `Book` class as a library. But if you want to get crazier, you can have another class called `Magazine` and that would be the child class of parent `Library`. Here is what that would look like.
[image: lib]

But this would get quite complicated, moreover, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to inherit `Book` from `Library`. Hence it is a good idea to keep `Library` as a separate that will merely control the books.

```py
class Library():
    def __init__(self,book_list = []):
        self.book_list = book_list

    def new_book(self,book):
        self.book_list.append(book)

    def remove_book(self,name): # book is the name of the book
        for book in self.book_list:
            if book.name == name:
                self.book_list.remove(book)
                break


    def print_books(self):
        for book in self.book_list:
            print(f"Book {book.name} by {book.author}")


class Book():
    def __init__(self,author,name):
        self.author = author
        self.name = name

    def print_book(self):
        print(f"{self.name} by {self.author}")




class Novel(Book):
    def __init__(self,author,name):
        Book.__init__(self,author,name)

    def display(self):
        print(f"The Novel {self.name}")
        # Novel stuff which isn't common in all books

class Comic(Book):
    def __init__(self,author,name):
        Book.__init__(self,author,name)

    def display(self):
        print(f"The comic book {self.name}")
        # Comic book stuff which isn't common in all books


my_lib = Library()
my_lib.new_book(Novel("J.K Rowling","Harry Potter"))
my_lib.new_book(Novel("Aryan Parekh","Stack"))

my_lib.remove_book("Stack")

my_lib.print_books()
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes having Book as the parent class would make more sense now I think about it. I'll be sure to change list as well. Regarding having magazine and book as child classes of library, I'm not quite sure how this would work. However this is probably just down to me not being that knowledgable regarding inheritance. What kind of methods would the parent class Library have in this instance?

Comment: @AaronWright It is not absolutely necessary that it would need to be a parent. In fact, I would recommend `Library` to be a separate class which would create a list of `Book` objects

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. I think this is similar to what I have, but just having subclasses of books which inherit from `Book`.

Comment: @AaronWright Inheritance is useful, but if you ask me, I would say no to use it in this scenario

Comment: Small suggestion/nitpick: it is common to just use `books` instead of `book_list`

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex. Thank you! I'll add that in. I'm actually trying to convert this into a GUI application which would allow one to add songs, remove songs, etc with buttons. Do you happen to know if this is possible with the current design I have?

Answer (score 8):

## Simplify the constructor of `class Library`

You have a default value of `None` for the parameter `books`, but then immediately proceed to convert that `None` to an empty list. Why not use `[]` as the default value?

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, books = []):
        self.books = list(books)

    ...
```

Note that to prevent the issue of [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) as mentioned by ojdo, you should make a copy of the initial list.

## Be consistent

You take an optional list of books in the constructor of `class Library`, but there is no such thing in `class ReadingList`. That is a bit surprising.

Also be consistent with naming things. In `class Library`, the list of books is called `books`, but in `class ReadlingList` you named it `list`. I would name it `books` in both cases.

Also be consistent with the names of functions:

- `get_library()` should be `get_books()`, since it only returns the list of books, not an object of type `Library`.
- `pages_over_n()` should be `get_books_with_over_n_pages()` or something similar, to indicate that it returns `Book`s, not pages.
- `total_pages()` should be renamed `get_total_pages()` or `calculate_total_pages()`. Prefer using verbs for function names, and nouns for variables.

And I also wonder why a `ComicBook` has an `artist`, but a `Novel` has no `author`? And why is there a `get_artist()` but no `get_title()`, `get_publication_date()` and so on? Making everything consistent will make using your classes much easier.

## Removing books from the Library

As you noticed, you can remove a book from the library, but it won't be removed from any reading lists. But that is fine. Why would a book magically disappear from a real life reading list if your library removes that book? Note that your code is perfectly fine, Python won't actually delete the `Book` object from memory until the last reference to it is gone.

However, if you want a book to disappear from the `ReadingList` when it is removed from the `Library`, then somehow there needs to be some communications between those two objects. There are two options:

1. A `Library` keeps a list of `ReadingList`s that reference its `Book`s, and when you call `remove_book()` on a `Library`, it will in turn iterate over all the `ReadingList`s and call `remove_book()` on them as well.
2. A `ReadingList` keeps a reference to the `Library` whose `Book`s it contains. Whenever you call a member function that accesses the list of books on the reading list, this member function first has to filter out all the books that are no longer in the `Library`.

Comment: Perfect thank you! This helps a lot. Your first point makes a lot more sense than what I've done. Regarding the lack of get methods, this is something I plan on adding in. For the reading list, my thinking was that if you remove a book from the Library, then you would also want it removed from the reading list. Sort of like removing a song from Spotify's library would remove it from a playlists (I would presume). Again, this is just a vague idea I have.

Comment: I fear the first recommendation [would backfire](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments), or do you know that this behaves differently within instance methods?

Comment: I would need to check. All I was looking for was to have an option whereby I can initialise class with either nothing, or initialise it with an array of books (rather than adding each one separately using the add_book method)

Comment: @ojdo You are right. But actually, even when you provide the argument you have to be aware that the list you provide might be modified by subsequent calls to `add_book()` and `remove_book()`, so I guess it's best to always create a copy of the list. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thank you for the update. I think number 1 on that list is what I initially tried, but ended up confusing myself. Logic I started with was that if a book was added to `ReadingList` using `add_book`, add the reading list to a predefined list in `Library` - however I just got myself in a jumble. Hopefully I'll better understand OOP the more I spend with it.

Comment: @AaronWright This has not much to do with OOP, but rather how variables work in Python.

Comment: I personally would a) not opt to do perform a copy operation and b) prefer the `books=None` idiom like in the question, but in total a helpful answer, +1.

Answer (score 6):

Since `Library` and `ReadingList` are just different types of lists of books, I would opt for define a generic `BookList` as a base class from which `Library` and `ReadingList` both inherit.

Doing this saves you from the repetition of having to define common methods like the following, which both of your classes already do. Here are some methods from the `Library` class.

```
def __init__(self, books = None):
    if books is None:
        self.books = []
    else:
        self.books = books

def add_book(self, book):
    self.books.append(book)
    
def remove_book(self, book):
    self.books.remove(book)
```

And here are the analogous methods from the `ReadingList` class.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.list = []

def add_book(self, book):
    """Add book to reading list"""
    self.list.append(book)
    
def remove_book(self, book):
    """Remove book from reading list"""
    self.list.remove(book)
```

As [G. Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250409/personal-book-library-with-python#answer-250413) said, you should simplify the `Library` constructor to match the `ReadingList` constructor. After you do this, the methods are exactly the same.

By defining a generic book list class, not only do you not have to keep redefining common functionality, you can also take advantage of polymorphic functions.

For example, rather than making each class responsible for outputting a string representation of itself, you could define a `BookListHTMLWriter` that takes a book list item (either a `ReadingList` or a `Library`, both are fine when they're derived from the same `BookList` object), and outputs an HTML table representation.

Likewise, you could also define a `BookListXMLWriter` that outputs the XML representation of a `BookList` object or a subclass thereof. You could take this OOP-refactoring even further by then refactoring the functionality common to the `BookListHTMLWriter` and `BookListXMLWriter` classes and derive them from a base `BookListWriter` base class.

Optimistically, object-oriented programming can be a bit of an acquired taste (and an esoteric one, at that), but once you start thinking in these terms it's a useful mental model, even if it's not your only one. Or you preferred one, even.

---

Regarding your point about how removing a book from your library does not remove it from your reading list(s), I agree with previous responses that this makes sense. I think the problem that you're alluding to might be the question of referential integrity, which I noticed, too.

You've obviously already noticed that `Library` and `ReadingList` are both lists of `Book`s. When reading over code, I always start picturing the corresponding database schema, and the problem I think you're referring to is that there should be a main list of already created books from which you can add to a personal library and/or reading list, presumably depending on whether you own the book. I would call this main list a "catalog" or something to differentiate this main list from a list of a particular type belonging to a particular user.

Moreover, this catalog would simply be all of the records in a `books` table in your database.

To implement a database for this program, you could start by creating the `books` and `users` tables, and then creating a third table consisting only of a user's id and a book's id. Querying this link table for a given user id would give you all of the books this person owns.

If you wanted users to be able to create arbitrary libraries based not just on whether they own a book, you would only need to create a `reading_lists` table with a user id as a field to indicate the owner, and then create another link table using a list id and a book id.

This would solve your referential integrity problem by preventing the deletion of a book record unless you specify an appropriate `ON DELETE` action in the `books` table schema.

Subclassing `Book`s into `Novel`s and `Magazine`s complicates things because if the inheritance hierarchy imbues complex enough differences on your subclasses, your objects no longer map nicely into single tables (assuming you want a reasonably-normalizable schema).

If you hit this point, a good entity-relational mapping tool can save you hours of frustration.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give some of this a go. Some of it may be a little advanced for me, however sounds like a good learning opportunity. Even defining `BookListXMLWriter` sounds like something I'll need to do a bit of research into.

Comment: Do you know where I could look to learn a bit more about implementing databases etc, or a link to something that has done something similar? It's a bit beyond my knowledge, but sounds interesting.

Comment: If you've never worked with databases before, I can't recommend [Beginning Databases with PostgreSQL](https://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Databases-PostgreSQL-Novice-Professional/dp/1590594789/ref=sr_1_4?crid=1UHQS185PLIG9&dchild=1&keywords=postgresql&qid=1602269514&s=books&sprefix=postgresql%2Caps%2C172&sr=1-4) enough. It was published years ago, but the content is still current. It walks you through the setup, designing a database, why even bother, etc. It's one of my favorite books of all time, I love it. (It's also only 11 bucks used) It's the book that got me started

Comment: Perfect thank you! I'll definitely take a look. I'm doing a course which includes databases and SQL - which I think starts in a couple months, but I'll try get a head start with that book!